# linking extra libraries/objects failed

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghci

I made FFI bindings to C++ unordered_map(a.k.a. hash_map) container and its wrapper library called `libstl.a`.
At the first time, it used to work well. But after some point, it has failed to link the library with the following error messages and I can't figure out why.

```
$ ghci -L. -lstl -lstdc++ 
GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading object (static archive) ./libstl.a ... done
Loading object (dynamic) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libstdc++.so ... done
final link ... ghc: ./libstl.a: unknown symbol `_ZZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEmE10__fast_bkt'
linking extra libraries/objects failed
```

Source codes for the library is located in https://github.com/comatose/stl-container. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems loading .o files into ghci.  From what I understand, the problem is that g++ leaves 'weak symbols' in .o files, and ghci doesn't deal with them very well.

I found a thread about it with a helpful follow-up:

http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-March/099926.html

in which the suggested solution is to put everything compiled by g++ into shared libraries (.so files instead of .a), and that seems to clear up the weak symbol problem.  Shared libraries can be a bit of a pain.  I suggest that you look at libtool.  It's a helper program that can handle a lot of the complications:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this. I don't think strip was any help, but I'm not 100% sure. Versions of GHC 7.8 and later seem to be able to load libraries with weak symbols, so they don't have this problem.