# using cabal to build ffi library that works in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, ffi

I'm trying to package up an ffi library with cabal. Compiling a module with the library works and runs fine, but I get an unknown symbol error in one of the extra-libraries dependencies when loading/running in ghci.

I know that people recommend compiling a separate shared library for ghci, like in this question: [linking extra libraries/objects failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004383/linking-extra-libraries-objects-failed)

However, I'm not sure how to rectify this within cabal. Could anybody explain to me what standard practice is in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried starting GHCi with `cabal repl`? Alternatively, you can run `ghci -lyourlib` to link against the extra-libraries.

Comment: so i can get it working, but not just by typing "cabal install", my concern is packaging up this library, putting it on hackage and hopefully have it be compatible with ghci right out of the box.